# how to manage and set equal size of figures through latex code

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

i am working in two columns format .. I put two graphs in one left column. I have to use tight layout in one of my python graph code to avoid label cropping. but now the problem is my two graphs become different in size, its not looking good. can we handle it through latex code?

here is my image
[image]

the code is this

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\columnwidth}
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fig9.PNG}}
  \caption{aaaaaaaaaaaa}
  \label{Fig9:aaaaaaaaaaaa}
\end{minipage}\hfill % maximize horizontal separation
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.475\columnwidth}
{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Fig10.PNG}}
  \caption{Gbbbb}
  \label{Fig10:bbbbbb}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Either the two images have different aspect ratios, or the width of write margins are not the same, or both. I think it's easier to config the graph size in python, so you only need to use `scale=<number>` option in LaTeX.

Comment: note that the size of the image to latex is the outer border including your sloping text along the axis, but visually you want the boxes with the main plots equal size. LaTeX has no information about that so don't ask it to scale, remove `[width=\linewidth]` and generate the images the size you need from python

Comment: You could use `tight_layout()` on the other graph as well.